# Linking to folders broken

Tags: github

I have a `README.markdown` file. The file sits at the top level of the repository.

The repository has many sub folders. The top level `README.markdown` provides links to the various folders, via the following:

```
[Another Folder](Another Folder/)
```

This was working fine until this morning, when all the links point gave a `404` response. Relative links to specific files still work:

```
[Another Folder's README](Another Folder/README.markdown)
```

But linking to the sub directory itself failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Someone else reported something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445387/relative-link-in-readme-broken-if-readme-viewed-automatically-by-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github support got back to me to say it's been fixed. Seems to be fixed for me now.

Comment: It is fixed. Thanks!